# Is it correct to use CallableStatement in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, prepared-statement, callable-statement

I'm still learning `JSF` but in the past I created project using `Swing` with `JDBC` and `MySQL` as `RDBMS`. So right now I'm working on a web project to become more familiar with `JSF`.

Most of the examples I saw online used `PreparedStatement` and I haven't seen any that used `CallableStatement`

I asked this because I think I'll need to use `SQL Transactions` to perform tasks. So, `CallableStatement` will definitely help me and I actually used `CallableStatement` in the past.

Also, I noticed that in the examples I saw, they never used the `try-with-resources` syntax which has auto-closing of resources

Consider my method below.

```
public void register() throws SQLException{
        String myFirstName = this.getFirstName();
        String myLastName = this.getLastName();
        String myMiddleName = this.getMiddleName();
        String myEmail = this.getEmail();
        try{
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDb");
        }catch(NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            if(dataSource == null){
                throw new SQLException("Can't get DataSource");
            }

        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            if(connection == null){ 
                throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to datasource"); 
            }

        try{
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO customer (firstName,lastName,middleName,email) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement addCustomer = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);
                addCustomer.setString(1, myFirstName);
                addCustomer.setString(2, myLastName);
                addCustomer.setString(3, myMiddleName);
                addCustomer.setString(4, myEmail);

        }finally{
            connection.close();
        }

    }
```

Is it possible for me to replace `PreparedStatement addCustomer = connection.prepareStatement(SQL);` with a

```
String SQL = "{call addCustomer (?,?,?,?)}";
callableStatement = conn.prepareCall(SQL);
```

If not, then what is the best solution to make use of `SQL Transactions` contained in `Stored Procedures` in `JSF`

I'd appreciate any example that will best help.

Thank you.

Comment: JSF is 'ignorant' about this. Use what suites you best but make sure it is still performant (so don't do work in a getter etc...)

Comment: Transactions are also not a privilege of stored procedures. You can perfectly well use `PreparedStatements` with transactions.